# Searching for MD5SUMS of 12.04 Daily Build on January 19th

Tags: md5sum

I downloaded and burned Precise Pangolin Daily Build on 19th January 2013 but forgot to gather the MD5Sum... which was a bad idea since I'd like to verify the file & disk now.
Is there an archive for Daily Builds MD5SUMs?

The iso file was called precise-desktop-amd64.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to make sure the file wasn't inadvertently [corrupted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_corruption) (rather than concerned about it being deliberately modified in a [man-in-the-middle attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)).

You'll likely have some difficulty finding the MD5SUM for the file. If it were a day older than what's on the server, you might find it on a mirror, but this is several days old.

What you should *instead* do is boot from it, hold down shift, and select *Check disc for defects*. This will give you the same information. (Unless it won't boot or won't get to that point--then it won't give you that information.)

- [Ubuntu CD Advanced Welcome Page Options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options)
- [ZootLinux tech blog post, showing a video of how to do it](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html) (they use 10.04 but it's the same)

It's fine if it's a USB flash drive, *Check disc for defects* still works properly (except for being confusingly named).

**But why are you using a daily build of a release two versions older than the current daily builds? Perhaps if you provide more detail in your question about what you're trying to achieve, better solutions could be given.**